# Period of time, a bit or a while

Tags: phrases, time

If I want to place my luggage at the hotel for a few hours, how is it best to ask if I can do this?

Should I ask the receptionist:

"Can I place my luggage here a bit?"

or

"Can I place my luggage here a while?"

Which one is more correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could ask the desk clerk:

> Could I leave my luggage/bags here (or *with you*) for an hour or two?

Or

> Could I leave my luggage/bags here/with you and pick it/them up when I get back (from lunch) in an hour or two ?

Or

> Could I leave my luggage/bags here/with you while I'm out (to lunch)? It'll not take long.

Or

> Do you mind if I leave my luggage/bags here/with you while I'm out (to lunch)? I'll be back shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you say that you are going to leave your luggage for at most a couple of hours. A bit or a while suggest a shorter period of time and may generate misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could say : 'Could I place my luggage here for an hour or two?'

Answer (score 0):

I think bit refers to a shorter amount of time while 'while' refers to a longer amount of time. Hope your question is answered

Answer (score 0):

I'm a former ESL teacher and native English speaker. It is better to be as specific as possible. People's interpretation of "bit" or "while" can differ and create frustration. It would be best to give an estimate if when you plan to return. For example, "Is it ok if I leave my luggage here until 5?" Or even to ask, "How long would it be possible for me to leave my luggage here?"